# Finding rank of matrix A^2 =A

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $A \in M(n,\mathbb{C})$ with $A^2 =A$ , then $rk(A)= tr(A)$ .
Is it true if yes then how can anyone explain?

Comment: Rearrange to find $A^2-A=0$ i.e. $A(A-I)=0$.  Now... what do you know about minimal polynomials and eigenvalues and how they relate to the rank and to the trace?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: How to delete this question .I was not aware that someone already asked it. It down voted me with 4 points

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $A^2=A$ means that $A(A-1)=0$ so you have that the polynomial $x(x-1) \in I(A)$. The only eigenvalues you have are $0$ and $1$ and surely the matrix is diagonalizable. So you can say that:

$$A \sim \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ & \ddots \\ &&1 \\ &&&0 \\ &&&&\ddots \\ &&&&&0\end{pmatrix}$$ So clearly you see that the rank is equal to the trace. (In fact, they are invariant under conjugation).

Answer (score 0):

Any [idempotent matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix) is diagonalizable, with eigenvalues $0$ and $1$. Since trace and rank are invariant under conjugation, the claim follows.